# « Je n’ai plus les moyens de t’aider » ou « Je n’ai plus les moyens pour t’aider »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

> Malheureusement je n’ai plus les moyens financiers/ressources financières de t’aider dans tes travaux de rénovation.

> Malheureusement je n’ai plus les moyens financiers/ressources financières pour t’aider dans tes travaux de rénovation.

Autre formulation:

> Malheureusement mes finances et mon temps disponible ne me permettent plus de te venir en aide dans tes travaux de rénovations.

D’autres tournures à proposer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les deux me paraissent aussi idiomatiques l'un que l'autre, mais une vérification par ngram montre que « les moyens de t'aider » est utilisé uniquement.

On trouve les verbes suivants et il y en a de nombreux autres.

les moyens pour empêcher, pour faciliter, pour relier, pour agir, pour continuer et intensifier, pour préserver,   pour persuader, pour défendre, pour s ' approvisionner, pour se tuer, pour favoriser , pour parvenir, pour nourrir, pour économiser, pour réduire, pour suivre

Alors, pourquoi trouver « les moyens pour t'aider » inacceptable ?

---

*Alternative qui raccourcit sans changer le sens*

- Malheureusement je n’ai plus les moyens de/pour subvenir à tes travaux de rénovation. (*« De » est très largement préféré.*)

Comment: Je me suis mal exprimé, ce que je voulais dire, c’est que je n’ai plus de temps à accorder à un ami pour l’aider dans ses travaux de rénovation sans rétribution en retour en exploitant mes aptitudes en charpenterie-menuiserie car j’ai des obligations et pour m’en acquitter, il me faut un travail rémunéré, ce qui demande du temps.

Comment: J’ai mis à jour les détails de la question.

Comment: @Thérèse C'est une toute autre question ; pour éviter un embrouillamini d'archive sur cette page pourquoi ne pas copier cette seconde et finale version, la poser en tant que nouvelle question puis effectuer un « roll-back » sur la présente page, puisque ce qui avait  été écrit en premier constituait une question valide ? De plus les votes attribués ne sigifieraient plus grand chose, si on mélangeait tout.